# Displaying ppt interactively on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have browsed and searched a lot for this but couldn't find any relevant answers/posts. I am looking for a framework/library with the help of which I can convert ppt slides into images and then render them on iOS device. Any other way/procedure which will display ppt page-wise with giving control on page transition will also be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the Office files, have a look at:

- [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS: Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html).
- [Quick Look Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html)

**Quick Look Framework** supports a lot of file formats as you can see in the links above. It is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

You can also use **UIWebView** to display them. See [Using UIWebView to display select document types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).

Comment: The quick look framework is of little help as it displays the file in a similar manner as the webView does. I am looking for a solution which can give me individual slides from a ppt, as I need more control on the way I can display the ppt.